# php shared memory cross browser

Tags: php, cross-browser, shared-memory

For example , I open 01.php in firefox , open 02.php in google chrome , 
**01.php create a shared memory segment** , now I 01.php write a msg to this shared memory segment ,
and I want **02.php to access this shared memory segement** and read the msg .
can it be successed ? And how to do ?

I only know that if use read-write file instead of use shared memory , it can be successed .

Comment: Memcache(d) is a memory cache that is designed for distribution. You should give it a go, very easy to get started.

Comment: I smell a huge [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You may want to explain what you *actually* want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If sharing memory is really what you want to achieve use the APC extension.

01.php

```
<?php
$bar = 'SOME VALUE';
apc_store('myuniquekey', $bar);
```

02.php

```
var_dump(apc_fetch('myuniquekey'));
```

**EDIT:**

There's another way i wasn't aware of - without using apc: http://php.net/shmop. It is little more complex and ugly as you have to allocate space and stuff, but it is more likely that the shmop extension is available without beeing required to install it manually.

```
$shm_id = shmop_open(0x123, 'c', 0644, 250);
shmop_write($shm_id, "Data in shared memory", 0);
$value = shmop_read($shm_id, 8, 6);
```